# Не работает свойство rotate, даже с display: inline-block

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

Я пытаюсь создать эффект паралакс, чтобы при движении мыши фон тоже двигался, однако это реализовать не получается - задник вообще никак не реагирует.

CSS:

```
.layers__container {
    
    height: 100vh;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(var(--move-y)) rotateY(var(--move-x));
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform var(--transition);
}
.layers__item {
 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
.layer-1 {
    transform: translateZ(-55px) scale(1.06);
}
.layer-2 {
    transform: translateZ(80px) scale(.88);
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    Object.assign(document.documentElement, {
        style: `
        --move-x: ${(e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * -.001}deg;
        --move-y: ${(e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2) * -.001}deg;
        `
    })
})
```

В интернете советуют применять display:block и display: inline-block, но это как-то не очень помогло (либо я не совсем понимаю как ими пользоваться)

Я новичок в Frontend, поэтому многое не догоняю пока, надеюсь на вашу помощь  :)

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает. Просто поворот на 0.1deg глазом не видно.
Вот тут я поменял коэффициент и сразу же стало заметно

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  Object.assign(document.documentElement, {
    style: `
        --move-x: ${(e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * -.1}deg;
        --move-y: ${(e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2) * -.1}deg;
        `
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  perspective: 100vh;
}

.layers__container {
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(var(--move-y)) rotateY(var(--move-x));
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform var(--transition);
  perspective: 100vh;
}


/* фон что бы было заметнее взят с https://css-pattern.com/ */

.layers__container {
  --s: 120px;
  /* control the size*/
  --_g: radial-gradient(#0000 70%, #1a2030 71%);
  background: var(--_g), var(--_g) calc(var(--s)/2) calc(var(--s)/2), conic-gradient(#0f9177 25%, #fdebad 0 50%, #d34434 0 75%, #b5d999 0);
  background-size: var(--s) var(--s);
}
```

```html
<div class="layers__container">
</div>
```